# File got deleted when moving to parent directory

Tags: command-line, bash

In Terminal, the working directory was set to `/mnt/qq/iso`.

I wanted to move a file from this directory to the parent directory qq, so I entered:

```
mv -v boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso ../
```

Instead of moving the file the file was removed. Could anyone explain why this happened and what is the correct way to transfer a file up 1 or more directory levels?

If I typed `cd ../` the wd would be changed to `qq`. So why would this not apply to transferring a file?

Comment: The command you posted seem valid. Are you sure, you typed the command exactly as written here? What was the output? something like `»boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso“ -> »../boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso“`?

Comment: Please post the results of `history` for the commands near this "mv" command ;) If there was something else behind the ../ the file got renamed (and if that started with a "." also check with `ls -la` if it became hidden)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this entry in the bash history and couldn't find it. Thinking there was a possibility that I unconsciously typed `rm` instead of `mv`, I searched for this entry with `rm` instead of `mv`, and it was not found. So I've duplicated this operation to determine whether this is a bug or an isolated quirk.

```
obalaban@BM:~/mnt/qq/iso$ touch boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso
obalaban@BM:~/mnt/qq/iso$ mv -v boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso ../
‘boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso’ -> ‘../boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso’
obalaban@BM:~/mnt/qq/iso$ ls ../
boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso  iso
```

#### Conclusion

The file was successfully moved to it's parent directory using `../` as the destination. Apparently, this file deletion is a quirk that defies explanation.